# Gambling: is it haram if i dont keep the profit gained? Is it haram if my loses are protected?

Tags: halal-haram, gambling

I don't know what came over me, all of a sudden i felt greed i never have before and went on this website and gambled. I lost my money and in desperation i kept playing in hope to just regain my money and said to myself ill never gamble again. I know its haram, i shouldn't have done it in the first place! i have no idea what came over me! i should have stopped myself. As i tried to regain my loss, i lost even more money. The gambling was online, on a trading platform, its based on rates of for example currencies going up or down. So then this happened. Its hard to explain but i am 'working' with someone now to trade my money in. So these people i agreed to work with have analysts, they analyses the pattern of the fall or rise and make predictions on whats about to happen next on the currency rate and based on that we place our trade. Because we work together, and they are confident in their analysis, i get full protection (as in, if we lose, i get my money returned by them to me, if i win, they gain a certain % themselves every time i win). So i pretty much just give them my money and they do the rest, and we both earn money. I have already placed the money, i am waiting for the results today.

So i have 2 questions:

1. i read somewhere on this website that some forms of gambling are
   acceptable, that non permitted gambling is associated with taking
   "unreasonable" risks. Since i am now protected, and if i lose money
   it will be returned by to me, is it still haram? as i am not taking
   a risk anymore really. I understand that the initial gambling i did
   was definitely haram, i was just going and relying on luck.

My second question is

2. if this all is still haram, and i win, would it be okay to just take
   the money i have used on this website back (my losses and what i
   used in this trade)? and get rid of all the profit (for example
   donate it to charity), because I'm thinking to do that anyway.

Please, i know i shouldn't have gambled in the first place, i don't know what came over me, but advice me of this current situation and if i should definitely pull out and end this horrible thing I've started even if it means losing all my money.

Comment: What you are doing now sounds just like a lending money on interest. You give money to someone, they do the job. You don't take any risk, but yet make profit. Just like depositing money in conventional banks.

Comment: @ozbek pretty much! Does that make it okay then?

Comment: I would think not.

Answer (score 2):

Gambling is forbidden.

> O you who believe! Intoxicants (all kinds of alcoholic drinks), and
>   gambling, and Al-Ansab , and Al-Azlam (arrows for seeking luck or
>   decision) are an abomination of Shaitan's (Satan) handiwork. So avoid
>   (strictly all) that (abomination) in order that you may be successful.

Do you see any conditions or concessions attached to the prohibition? No! That leaves only one conclusion that all gambling is unconditionally haram, regardless of whether you think you deserve the gains or how much risk you take or what you do with the profit.